# Sql query for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have five tables "ArtBook,Eng,comm,Law,mgt" and every table has a same column and i want to be search all the information that particular book by its id
e.g-

```
select * from ArtBook,Eng,Comm,Law,mgt where @BookId=ArtBooks.BookId
or @BookId=CommBooks.BookId
or @BookId=Eng.BookId
or @BookId=Law.BookId
or @BookId=mgt.BookId
```

Comment: You would need a `UNION ALL` rather than a `JOIN` but it doesn't seem like the correct structure to me. Why not one table for books with either a column for genre or a separate junction table if you want to allow for books that span multiple genres.

Answer (score 3):

If all the tables store books of different categories, then combine them back into one table and add a 'category' column. Categorising into separate tables like this isn't a good idea for the reasons you've demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from ArtBook
where BookId = @BookId
union all
select * 
from Eng
where BookId = @BookId
union all
select * 
from Comm
where BookId = @BookId
union all
select * 
from Law
where BookId = @BookId
union all
select * 
from Mgt
where BookId = @BookId
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use the UNION or UNION ALL operator.

```
(SELECT * FROM ArtBook)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM Eng)
...
WHERE @BookId=ArtBooks.BookId or
       @BookId=CommBooks.BookId or 
       @BookId=Eng.BookId or 
       @BookId=Law.BookId or 
       @BookId=mgt.BookId
```

et cetera, et cetera. Though you may consider restructuring how your data is stored to make this sort of thing easier.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause just needs one condition in each part of the `UNION ALL` not 5.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better form, changing answer to reflect that.